# como deixar express asincrono?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express.js

estou tendo um problema com esse codigo:

```
const express = require("express")


const app = express()

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms)
    })
}
  
async function teste() {
    await sleep(10000)
    return "teste"
}
  
app.get("/teste", async (_, res) => {
    const t = await teste()
    res.send(t)
})

app.listen(80)
```

se eu deixar sem o await ele retorna uma pagina em branco, e se eu der await ele bloqueia o codigo pros outros requests

**por ex:**
ele só vai fazer o request 2 quando terminar o 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não há nada o que fazer, o Express já gerencia requisições de forma assíncrona.

---

O que eu vou fazer aqui é apenas uma suposição: o seu problema não está no servidor, mas sim no seu cliente.

Uma das formas que eu imagino que você possa estar tendo problemas, é no seu front-end, onde você está fazendo duas requisições idênticas, e a segunda só começa a processar depois que a primeira termina.

Por exemplo, se você rodar o seguinte na sua página (ou no console do navegador):

```
fetch('/teste').then(res => res.text()).then(payload => console.log(payload));
fetch('/teste').then(res => res.text()).then(payload => console.log(payload));
```

Você poderá observar que terá um intervalo de 10 segundos entre a resolução de uma requisição e a outra. Esse é o intervalo programado no servidor. Mas na verdade o que está acontecendo é que o seu navegador está esperando a primeira requisição terminar para começar a outra, não é o seu servidor quem está esperando. Como as requisições são idênticas, o navegador está tentando fazer o que ele acha mais otimizado.

Se por outro lado você "enganar" o navegador, tentando parecer que duas chamadas terão resultados diferentes, como por exemplo:

```
fetch('/teste?a').then(res => res.text()).then(payload => console.log(payload));
fetch('/teste?b').then(res => res.text()).then(payload => console.log(payload));
```

Nesse caso não haverá otimização, e ele fará as duas requisições simultaneamente, e você receberá as respostas simultaneamente.

Comment: o problema não é no frontend, eu abri 2 abas no navegador mesmo e dei enter, um só inicia quando o outro termina

Comment: Ana, mesmo que você fizer as requisições em abas diferentes você ainda vai ter o problema. Faça o teste enviando um parâmetro como eu coloquei no exemplo e verifique o resultado.